# How to load a .java file from a specified path and retrieve the declared methods in it?

Tags: java, class, classloader

I want to load a .java file from a specified path and retrieve the methods declared in it. Please find below the sample.

There is a java file in a location `D:/Sample/Test.java`

I have declared two methods in it `test1()` and `test2()`.`

I know that by using `classobj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()` I can retrieve the methods declared in it. But my problem is in loading the `.java` file.

Could anyone please provide me a solution for this..

Regards,
Adarsh K S

Comment: You can't load .java files, they have to be compiled to .class files first.

Comment: Consider having a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes/21544850#21544850) which demonstrates the dynamic compliation of a `.java` file and loading of the resulting class file

Answer (score 3):

First you need to compile that java class

then you can use `URLClassLoader` to load class from specific location and then you can invoke `getDeclaredMethods()`