# Compiling and using Java from within another .jar file

Tags: java

Is it possible to Compile a .java file from within a java program and use that compiled java file for use within the java program. For use in scripting outside of the initial java program?

Comment: yes, You could compile any javasource file and initialize that file using classloader.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes

Comment: Other then the ClassLoader docs do you have any examples?