# Using Runtime.exec to Safely Compile and Execute a .java File

Tags: java, multithreading, process, server, runtime.exec

After having read a lot of similar questions about Runtime.exec and Java, I've not encountered a safe and clean idiom for compiling and running a .java file. I have just finished reading the "When Runtime.exec() won't" article, which helped me understand the general do's and don't's, but does not provide this idiom I'm looking for.

Overall I'm trying to create separate processes that will compile and run in series (multiple servers), without hanging or leaving any orphan processes. I'm not well-versed with these topics, so I am looking for more pointers.

So far I am able to compile the file by doing this:

```
try {            
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("javac Server.java");
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);

 } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: You could use the `JavaCompiler` class, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes/21544850#21544850)

Comment: As a general rule; 1- Use `ProcessBuilder`, it's far more configurable; 2- Make sure you read and process the output stream of the `Process`

Comment: What is the use of reading and processing the output?

Comment: Some process stall if the output buffer is not read.  It would also be useful to know if the process fails for some reason and why

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.