# How would I compile Java with Java?

Tags: java

This is a question that sounds funny, but when you think about it, how does it work? I tried it in the example below:

```
package folder;

public class JavaCompiler {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            //I use the Path class and passes it as an argument.
        Path path = Paths.get("folder\\File.java");
        new JavaCompiler().start(path);
    }

    public void start(Path path){
            //
        Process compiler = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac " + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
    }
}
```

And here is the class that I am compiling, easy enough right?

```
package folder;

public class File {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello Java Compiler!");
    }
}
```

So how would I do it?

Comment: How would you do what? Other than what you've done? What happened when you tried it? Unclear what you're asking. NB This is *not* [tag:compiler-construction].

Comment: Take a look at using `ClassLoader` to load classes at runtime. It isn't exactly what you asked for, but it may be what you need.

Comment: Look at this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/JavaCompilertoolshowyoucancompileaJavasourcefrominsideaJavaprogram.htm)

Comment: @TheCoffeeKid:  The duplicate already points to something similar.

Comment: Oh lol, I didn't see that; I was looking at the link and didn't refresh this page yet.

Comment: Well how would I then run that file?

Comment: Run what file? What's the question?

Comment: The compiled file at the end...

Comment: That's a completely new question.

Comment: Well how would I do it?

Comment: You would ask a new question. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. Nobody will ever see your new question here.

Comment: You can also do this without the need for executing an external command, take a look at [How do you dynamically compile and load external java classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes/21544850#21544850) which demonstrates a how to compile, load and run the resulting class