# Task.Call() not working -- Eclipse Plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an Eclipse plug-in that is compiling JAVA files upon click of the plug-in button.

Thanks to this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes/21544850#21544850), MadProgrammer gave the perfect solution for the requirement. I now have a project that can compile and run classes from an external folder.

Now, I am trying to port this into a plug-in. I have created the commands and tried to plug the same code into the plug-in code but nothing happens. I found out that `task.call()` is not working.

The code by MadProgrammer that works in a JAVA project class:

```
     DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
     JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
     StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
     List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
     optionList.add("-classpath");
     optionList.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path") + ";dist/InlineCompiler.jar");
     Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnit = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(listOfFiles));
     JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnit);
     if (task.call()) { 
           //insert logic here 
     }
```

The only difference that I found is that if I run the code in a JAVA class, `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` returns the build path of the JAVA project. However, when I run the code as a plug-in, the same code returns:
`C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar`

I am quite unsure if this is really the reason why `compiler.getTask()` isn't working. Aside from that, everything else is the same: this includes the classes to be compiled, the jdk version, etc.

Any input or advice on what should I do is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

**Update:** I found out that the JAVA project works even without:

```
 List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
 optionList.add("-classpath");
 optionList.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path") + ";dist/InlineCompiler.jar");
```

and setting null at the option list for `compiler.getTask()`, so I'm looking into the files that are being compiled, but so far, they're the same with the exception for the name of the package in the `implements`.

**2nd Update:** Diagnostics showed the following errors: `package xxxxplugin_handlers.CheckHandler does not exist` and `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`.

Here's a snippet of the file I am trying to compile:

```
public class checkClass implements xxxxplugin.handlers.CheckHandler.DoStuff{

@Override
public String doStuff(String code)
{
    //class function here
}
```

Comment: How is it 'not working'? Do you get messages? If so what are they?

Comment: Hi @greg-449, basically, task.call returns false and no .class files are generated.

Comment: @greg-449, it seems I have forgotten about the part where it shows the diagnostics when the call fails. I added it and it shows that: my errors are `public class checkClass implements xxxxplugin.handlers.CheckHandler.DoStuff` and `@Override`

Comment: @greg-449: Further looking into it, it gives this error message: `package xxxxplugin.handlers.CheckHandler does not exist.` and `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype` which is weird. I have the class created along with the 'supertype' doStuff.

Comment: Eclipse plug-ins have their own specialized classpath so you may need to do more work to set up the compilation classpath. I am not an expert on JavaCompiler so I don't know how you would do that.

Comment: Hi @greg-449. I'm confused on why it says package does not exist when it clearly exists and handlers under that package are working fine. Are there any known issues similar to this?