# defineClass method throws java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1885430635 in class file

Tags: java

I have tried the following code, and got an exception. Can someone help me with this,

```
package defineClass;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DefineClass extends ClassLoader {

    static String PATH = "E:\\WorkSpaceOpkey\\tester\\src\\test2\\Bar.java";

    public static void main(String[] m) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PATH);
        byte[] b = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(b);
        new DefineClass().defineClass("test2.Bar", b, 0, b.length);
    }

}
```

i am getting following error in defining class

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic 
value 1885430635 in class file test2/Bar
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at defineClass.DefineClass.main(DefineClass.java:14)
```

Comment: For reading a file system file use `byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(PATH));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply not possible, as class loaders load **compiled** classes:

> Converts an array of bytes into an instance of class Class,

You can't use a ClassLoader to *load* a java **source code** file.

If you want to dynamically use java source code, you will have to **compile** that source code into bytecode first, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes) for options how to do that.

The real answer of course: don't just **assume** what classes do. Always read their corresponding java doc, and do more research. There are many good resources that explain class loaders in detail, like [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders).