# Can you use Java reflections to define and invoke a method at runtime?

Tags: java, reflection

I've only read a bit about reflections, so I really don't know much.

I'm looking to build a program (class task) where the user writes a method implementation in a provided text box, which then should be invoked.
I was wondering if this can be done using reflections? Or is there a different way?

Comment: No, not really.  You "could" use it to call the method, once it's compiled.  See [How do you dynamically compile and load external java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes/21544850#21544850) for an example of how you could dynamically compile and load a class at runtime

Comment: Well, you *can* implement a compiler completely in Java, so this task is solvable with the core API alone, as it all boils down to make a class out of the bytecode, which you can do via [`MethodHandles.lookup().defineClass(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineClass(byte%5B%5D)) or by creating a subclass of `ClassLoader` and invoking one of its `defineClass(…)` methods. If you don’t want to implement your own compiler, you have to use the compiler API, which is beyond core Reflection.

Comment: runtime compiling is a possible action in many languages such as squeak(smalltalk). However, to achieve such a thing in Java is a different thing. maybe before java moved to JIT technique it was easier with an interpreter but anyhow I don't understand how reflection can help you.

Answer (score 0):

While it's certainly possible to achieve what's you're describing, it's infinitely easier to use a scripting language for such dynamic expressions.
JDK still has a JavaScript engine built-in, but you can add 3rd party engines easily. If you really want Java to be the language used in the dynamic scripts, one idea is to use [JShell script engine wrapper](https://github.com/eobermuhlner/jshell-scriptengine).

Either way, the approach would go like this:

```
//Read the code to evaluate
String scriptCode = ...;

//Init the engine of choice
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); //Or "jshell" or whatever

//Add all implicit variable values (if any)
Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
bindings.put("variableName", variableValue);

//Execute
engine.eval(scriptCode, bindings));
```

[BeanShell](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell) or Groovy are other Java-like options.